# Regex split only on certain characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text that I need to split...

```
'(!false =>stuff <300^ OR <=200 "TEST DATA")'
```

There are a couple of rules. I need to preserve quoted texts. Also, the delimiters I need to split on are the following...

```
{'<', '>', '<=', '=>', '=', '!', '(', ')'}
```

In this case, my split is the following...

```
['(', '!', 'false', '=>', 'stuff', '<', '300^', 'OR', '<=', '200', '"TEST DATA"', ')']
```

I've gotten close...

```
input_text.match(/"[^"]*"|=[<>]|[<>]=|[<>]|[!]|[=]|[()]|\w+/g);
```

It works for the most part, except for one thing, character such as `^` are not kept. So instead of getting...

```
300^
```

I'm getting just...

```
300
```

How can I keep every string intact and only split of the delimiters mentioned?

Comment: Why `'>='` and not `'=>'`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry that might have been a typo, where do you see that?

Comment: `['(', '!', 'false', '>=', ...`

Comment: @CertainPerformance fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like when you match `\w+`, you also want to match `^`s in that same matched substring, so make a character set and include `^` in that character set, as well as `\w`:

```js
const input_text = '(!false =>stuff <300$$^300 OR <=200 "TEST DATA")';
console.log(
  input_text.match(/"[^"]*"|=[<>]|[<>]=|[<>]|[!]|[=]|[()]|[\w^$]+/g)
  //                                                      ^^^^^
);
```

If all but the last alternations of the regular expression take care of all the special cases, then another option is to, instead of matching *word* (and selected special) characters finally, you could match *anything but a whitespace character* (the initial alternations will take priority, if any match):

```js
const input_text = '(!false =>stuff <300$$^300 OR <=200 "TEST DATA")';
console.log(
  input_text.match(/"[^"]*"|=[<>]|[<>]=|[<>]|[!]|[=]|[()]|[^\s]+/g)
  //                                                      ^^^^^
);
```

Comment: I see, but I want to keep all special characters, not only `^`, for example if I have a `$` I wan to keep that as well, will this preserve that?

Comment: Then put all such special characters you want to preserve into the character set with the word characters

Comment: You might also be able to just match non-whitespace characters after all the delimiter alternations are taken care of